# i am not able to see logs on kibana dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, kibana, filebeat, elk

I am using the ELK stack (elasticsearch, logstash, kibana) for log processing and analysis in a Kubernetes environment. To capture logs I am using filebeat.

The service account, the cluster role, and the cluster role binding of elasticsearch below yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - "services"
  - "namespaces"
  - "endpoints"
  verbs:
  - "get"
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-system
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: elasticsearch
  apiGroup: ""
```

elasticsearch service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: db
  selector:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch
  externalIPs:
  - 10.10.0.82
```

Elastic search statesul set yaml below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 2
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: elasticsearch
      containers:
      - image: elasticsearch:6.8.4
        name: elasticsearch
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: "2Gi"
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: "1Gi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: db
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
        env:
        - name: "NAMESPACE"
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      initContainers:
      - image: alpine:3.6
        command: ["/sbin/sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        name: elasticsearch-init
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        k8s-app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

pv & pvc0 yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elklogs-pv0
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  nfs:
    server: 10.10.0.131
    path: /opt/data/vol/0
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: data-elasticsearch-0
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

pv_pvc1.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elklogs-pv1
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  nfs:
    server: 10.10.0.131
    path: /opt/data/vol/1

---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: data-elasticsearch-1
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

logstash_svc.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5044
    targetPort: 5044
  externalIPs:
  - 10.10.0.82
```

logstash_config.yaml

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-configmap
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }
    filter {
      grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
      }
      date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      }
      geoip {
          source => "clientip"
        }
      }
      output {
        elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["http://10.10.0.82:9200"]
      }
    }
```

logstash deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash-deployment
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.3.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.yml
              path: logstash.yml
      - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.conf
              path: logstash.conf
```

filebeat.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.config:
      prospectors:
        # Mounted `filebeat-prospectors` configmap:
        path: ${path.config}/prospectors.d/*.yml
        # Reload prospectors configs as they change:
        reload.enabled: false
      modules:
        path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
        # Reload module configs as they change:
        reload.enabled: false
    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["http://10.10.0.82:5044"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-prospectors
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  kubernetes.yml: |-
    - type: docker
      containers.ids:
      - "*"
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat

    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.8.4
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: prospectors
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/prospectors.d
          readOnly: true
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: prospectors
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-prospectors
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
```

kibana.yaml

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kibana-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kibana-logging
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana-logging
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.8.4
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
            value: http://10.10.0.82:9200
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
          name: ui
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
    kubernetes.io/name: "Kibana"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: ui
    nodePort: 32010
  selector:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
```

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system
elasticsearch      ClusterIP   10.43.50.63    10.10.0.82    9200/TCP                 31m
kibana-logging     NodePort    10.43.58.127   10.10.0.82    5601:32010/TCP           4m4s
kube-dns           ClusterIP   10.43.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   23d
logstash-service   ClusterIP   10.43.130.36   10.10.0.82    5044/TCP                 30m
```

filebeat pod logs :

```
2020-11-04T16:42:22.857Z        INFO    log/harvester.go:255    Harvester started for file: /var/lib/docker/containers/011d24d334bba573ffbb466b0f3f70ae5ddc986f233e683076eaae7394801203/011d24d334bba573ffbb466b0f3f70ae5ddc986f233e683076eaae7394801203-json.log
2020-11-04T16:42:22.983Z        INFO    pipeline/output.go:95   Connecting to backoff(async(tcp://logstash-service:9600))
2020-11-04T16:42:52.412Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":270,"time":{"ms":271}},"total":{"ticks":740,"time":{"ms":745},"value":740},"user":{"ticks":470,"time":{"ms":474}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":97},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"6584086a-eff4-46b5-9be0-93892dad9d97","uptime":{"ms":30191}},"memstats":{"gc_next":36421840,"memory_alloc":32140904,"memory_total":55133048,"rss":65593344}},"filebeat":{"events":{"active":4214,"added":4219,"done":5},"harvester":{"open_files":89,"running":88,"started":88}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0},"reloads":2},"output":{"type":"logstash"},"pipeline":{"clients":2,"events":{"active":4117,"filtered":88,"published":4116,"total":4205}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":5,"update":5},"writes":{"success":6,"total":6}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":8},"load":{"1":1.9,"15":0.61,"5":0.9,"norm":{"1":0.2375,"15":0.0763,"5":0.1125}}}}}}
2020-11-04T16:42:54.289Z        ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://logstash-service:5044)): dial tcp 10.43.145.162:5044: i/o timeout
2020-11-04T16:42:54.289Z        INFO    pipeline/output.go:93   Attempting to reconnect to backoff(async(tcp://logstash-service:5044)) with 1 reconnect attempt(s)
```

```
logstash pod logs :
[WARN ] 2020-11-04 15:45:04.648 [Ruby-0-Thread-4: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:232] elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch"}
```

Comment: What address do you use to see kiaban?

Comment: http://195.134.187.25:32010/

Comment: Is there any error? Are pods up and running? Can you share output of `kubectl get svc -n kube-system`?

Comment: `elasticsearch      ClusterIP   10.43.50.63    10.10.0.82    9200/TCP                 31m`
 `kibana-logging     NodePort    10.43.58.127   10.10.0.82  5601:32010/TCP    4m4s`
`kube-dns           ClusterIP   10.43.0.10     <none>      53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP 23d`
`logstash-service   ClusterIP   10.43.130.36   10.10.0.82    5044/TCP               `@MariuszK.

Comment: @Behnam please help me out.

Comment: @MariuszK. please help me out.

Comment: @Eric Broda please help me out

Answer (score 2):

What I have understood from your architecture, you are using **Filebeat** >> **Logstash** >> **Elasticsearch** >> **Kibana**

So, in the `filebeat.yml`, you have selected output as logstash. But, you have given wrong port for logstash output in `filebeat.yml`.

It should be:

```
output.logstash:
  hosts: ['http://195.134.187.25:5044']
```

As, if you see in `logstash_config.yaml`, you have given 5044 as beats input. So, make the changes in `filebeat.yml` in `output.logstash`

Comment: Thanku for your reply @Sourav Atta but i have tested above hosts: ['http://195.134.187.25:5044'] but no output.     Actually i am trying filebeat vcan directily send to elastic search

Comment: Oh Ok. Then, in that case can you need to change the `[output.logstash]` to `[output.elasticsearch]` in `filebeat.yml`

Comment: is my deployment files are correct?..Please check @sourav-atta

Comment: Its little bit mess to understand, could you please try and if you face any error, add that error here. Check for the harvester as well when running filebeat, if the harvester is not running, then no logs will be stashed to elasticsearch.

Comment: please help me out... i have added logs of filebeat and logstash  above there is error .

Comment: As already mentioned in above comments, and also by seeing logs, The error is because you are connecting filebeat to logstash and the input port for beat in **logstash.yml** is 5044 but in **filebeat.yml**, under **[output.logstash]** you have given 9600 port. That’s why the error. You have to give 5044 port under **[output.logstash]** in filebeat.yml

Comment: it was typo mistake. @Sourave Atta